# Trying to run Monogame and it does not work. Missing logo and content not working

Tags: file, visual-studio-2019, monogame

It is my first year learning programming at college and we are using monogame to develop a Space Invaders game. I installed and reinstalled VS2019 and Monogame several times, followed all the steps and it does not work. When I open a new project It displays differently from my colleagues and my lecturer. The logo is missing and replaced by a strange black square thing with a "humanoid figure". Also when I get in the program itself it does not display the logo on the Content.mgcb and when I try to add a PNG. image for the Sprite to the content folder it does not work because is missing the .xnb file. I already tried to use a PNG to .XNB converter and it does not work unless I go manually to the content folder and paste the xnb file there. After "fix" that the next problem is to add the fonts, as I am not able to add them troughtout the content pipeline I can not continue with it. I am highly frustrated and my lecturer does not know what is wrong with it. If any of you could help me I would really appreciate it. Thank you. (I add some screenshots so you can see it).

P.S.: I have two users in my laptop, both are Admins, if that is any help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eypF3.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXGTb.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5tef.png)

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are many gotchas to the 3.8 version of Monogame and they have changed many things with the update, so you'll need to tread carefully.

They have a forum, and a post about the current version here: https://community.monogame.net/t/monogame-3-8/13312

They advise going through the getting started guide here:
https://docs.monogame.net/articles/getting_started/0_getting_started.html

The Content Builder (MGCB) program not executing properly is also the topic of a forum post.

Personally I had so many problems with 3.8 (nuget based) that I reverted to 3.7.x (installer based) but I wouldn't advise that unless there are problems you really can't overcome.

Comment: Amen to that. Spent the weekend installing it and reconfiguring my previous projects. I was starting to doubt myself.

Comment: Did I see you over on the Monogame forums? Did it turn out that you had a SPACE in your username that was the cause of your problems with the NuGet packages?